# C++ / VS 2010: Bug(s) occur only when running without a debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

This is a twisted problem. When I run my program using F5 in Visual Studio, everything works fine. If I start it without the debugger, or from outside VS, a few nasty bugs which I can't locate occur.

I suspect this is caused by the debugger randomizing all uninitialized variables, wheras "outside", they are set to 0. I must be using a variable without initing it somewhere...

- Are there other possible explanations?
- What should I do to find the bug - I can't use a debugger for it can I
- How come the debugger in VS doesn't detect the use of an unitialized variable, if that's the case

Comment: It is the other way around, the debug build initializes them but they are random in release.  The init value is 0xcccccccc, a value likely to cause faults.  But not guaranteed.

Comment: Are you talking about running the same binary in the debugger vs. not, or are you talking about running a Release build outside the debugger vs. running a Debug build inside the debugger?  If the latter, try running the Release build in the debugger.

Comment: By the way the VS 2010 does detect when variables are used before being initialized, though I'd bet there are ways to fool it.  I'm not sure in which version of VS that kind of detection was introduced.

Comment: Also, if the VS debugger isn't any help, try the WinDBG or CDB debuggers from the Windows Debugging Tools package that's in the SDK.  They might not introduce the heisenbug effect.  Of course, there's always 'binary search debugging' - remove stuff until the problem goes away to narrow down where to look. And don't forget about `printf()` debugging - sometimes that's all you can do...

Comment: @Michael Burr: I have tried both, release and debug build binaries ran in both VS with a debugger, and outside. Same results.

Answer (score 4):

As Hans Passant says, you have it the wrong way round. In Debug, memory is initialised, but in release it could be anything.

In general, if you have something going wrong in release that doesn't happen in debug then it could be down to a few things:

1. Relying on uninitialised variables as you said.
2. Optimisations changing the semantics of your code. This will only happen if you write code that is relying on ill-defined behaviour. For example, assuming that function arguments are evaluated in a specific order, or relying on signed integer overflow, or any number of things.
3. It's a timing issue that shows up more often in release builds due to the better performance. These most often occur in multithreaded applications.
4. You use different libraries in debug and release and rely on the different behaviour between them.

You can use the debugger to attach to a running program. I think it's in the 'Debug' menu in VS and is called 'Attach to process...'. Make sure that you generate debug symbols for release builds so that you get a usable call stack.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently except it was even weirder. The code worked fine when I ran release in visual studio, but when I ran the program outside visual studio (just clicked the .exe) it would do this very big bug.

Turned out it was because of:

```
angle = MathHelper.ToRadians(angle);
```

When ever angle was 0 it would fail and produce some weird results. 
I fixed it by simply changing it to:

```
angle = MathHelper.ToRadians(angle+.01f);
```

Very very annoying problem for something so small. Hopefully this helps others find similar errors.

Comment: This does not answer the question: you do not elaborate on the process you followed to find your problem.